# Is the union of two sets which are complement of locally closed sets, again complement of a locally closed set?

Tags: general-topology

Locally closed set: A set is said to be locally closed if it can be expressed as the intersection of an open set and a closed set.
My question is about the union of two sets which are complements of locally closed sets. Is it locally closed or complement of a locally closed set or neither of them?
My claim is that it will not be the complement of a locally closed set. But I failed to find any example. If anyone can help, it will be a great pleasure of mine.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ be the ambient space, and $C_1,C_2$ closed subsets, $U_1,U_2$ open subsets, so that
$D_i=X\setminus C_i\cap U_i$ are two complements of locally closed sets. Then:
$$
D_1\cup D_2=(X\setminus C_1\cap U_1)\cup(X\setminus C_1\cap U_1)=X\setminus(C_1\cap U_1)\cap(C_2\cap U_2)
$$
$$
=X\setminus (C_1\cap C_2)\cap(U_1\cap U_2),
$$ 
and $(C_1\cap C_2)\cap(U_1\cap U_2)$ is locally closed.

The result fails for arbitrary intersections. The subsets of $\mathbb R^2$ defined by
$$
S_n=\{y\ge0\}\setminus\{y=0,|x|\ge\!\tfrac{1}{n}\}
$$
are all locally closed, but 
$$
\bigcap_n S_n=\{y\ge0\}\setminus\{y=0,x\ne0\}
$$
is not.

Comment: But I am in a confused situation when I am considering the union of locally closed sets. Is it possible to find an example, by which we can say that the union of locally closed sets may not be locally closed.By the way thank you RS.

Answer (score 0):

(This was a bit long for a comment) The union of two locally closed sets may well not be locally closed. For instance, take an open half-plane $Y=\{x>0\}\subset\mathbb R^2$ and a closed disc tangent to $Y$, namely $Z=\{(x-1)^2+y^2\le 1\}$. Then the union is not locally closed. The easiest check is that $X=Y\cup Z$ is not locally compact (what would be if it were loc closed). Indeed, the obstruction is at the origin $(0,0)\in X$: no nbdh $V$ of the origin *in $X$* can be compact, as one can always find in $V$ sequences $\{(-\frac{1}{n},\varepsilon): n\ge1\}$, with $\varepsilon>0$ small enough, whose limit $(0,\varepsilon)$ is not in $X$.