# what is the union of two locally closed set?

Tags: general-topology

what about the union of two locally closed set? if it is not locally closed, I need an example.
Also what about the union of two sets which are complements of locally closed sets? If it is again complement of a locally closed set? If not, then I need again an example.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please share what you have tried so far and exactly where you have problem. Also add the necessary references and definitions. By the way, is it a hone work problem?

Answer (score 4):

First note that open sets and closed sets are locally closed: they are intersections of themselves with the whole space, which is both closed and open. Let

$$A=[0,1]\setminus\left\{\frac1n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\right\}=\{0\}\cup\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb Z^+}\left(\frac1{n+1},\frac1n\right)\;.$$

$\{0\}$ is closed in $\Bbb R$, and $\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb Z^+}\left(\frac1{n+1},\frac1n\right)$ is open in $\Bbb R$, so both of these sets are locally closed in $\Bbb R$, and $A$ is therefore the union of two locally closed sets. Suppose that $A$ is locally closed, so that there are an open set $U$ and a closed set $F$ such that $A=U\cap F$. Then $0\in U$, so there is an $\epsilon>0$ such that $(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\subseteq U$. Choose any $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that $\frac1n<\epsilon$; then $\frac1n\in U\setminus A$, so $\frac1n\notin F$. However,

$$\left(\frac1{n+1},\frac1n\right)\subseteq A=U\cap F\subseteq F\;,$$

and $F$ is closed in $\Bbb R$, so

$$\frac1n\in\left[\frac1{n+1},\frac1n\right]=\operatorname{cl}\left(\frac1{n+1},\frac1n\right)\subseteq F\;.$$

This contradiction shows that $A$ cannot be locally closed.

Your second question [has already been answered](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1204792/12042).